# How Can I set the time format in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do a real-time bidding system in php and I am struggling with displaying the time format. I did the time Subtraction in the sql query and I am getting the time in this format  -91100. So How can i display it in this format hh/mm/ss ?

here is my query

```
$sql = "select CURTIME()-time as newtime,id,name,end_date  from product";
```

Comment: whats the field type for *time* in the db?

Comment: The type is time in the database @Dagon

Comment: `SELECT TIMEDIFF(CURTIME(),time) as newtime`

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you very much @fusion3k

Comment: @fusion3k didn't copy you honest, just got distracted by work and forgot to refresh the page :-)

Comment: @Dagon I well know. No doubt about that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you subtract to time expressions from each other, then you get the difference is seconds. To convert seconds back to time format, use [sec_to_time()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) function:

```
select sec_to_time(CURTIME()-time) as newtime,id,name,end_date  from product
```

Answer (score 2):

`TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(CURTIME(),time), '%H:%i:%s') as newtime`

i chose a different approach to shadow and used TIMEDIFF(), added format to if you require that